# Extracting information from OpenCV descriptors

Tags: python, opencv

Let's say I calculate the keypoints and descriptors of a given image, for example with the ORB algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('simple.jpg',0)

orb = cv.ORB_create()
kp = orb.detect(img,None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
```

How can I extract the properties of these descriptors in order to study them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypoints are a list of objects of type [`Keypoint`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html), which comes from C++. You can access its public attributes as `kp[0].pt`, for the 2D position of the keypoint, for example. You can find the list of public attributes in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html).

The descriptors, on the other hand, are just a list of lists, each with 32 elements.